# value in .each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

when i use jQuery .each() function, it is give me index and value of current element. 
I have a this code

```
$('.scrollbar').each(function (index, value) {
     //some code   
});
```

the `value` is an DOM or jQuery object

Comment: Try console.log(value) to find out!

Comment: @ChrisHeald. Or look at the Jquery site.

Answer (score 3):

It's the underlying DOM object. It's easy to be proven:

```
$('.scrollbar').each(function(index, value) {
    alert(value.jquery);
});
```

shows `undefined`.

Whereas:

```
$('.scrollbar').each(function(index, value) {
    alert($(value).jquery);
});
```

shows the version of jQuery which is attached to all jQuery objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this:

```
$('.scrollbar').each(function (index, value) {
     var DOM = this,
         jq = $(this);
});
```

The value refers to the same object as the `this` object, so it will be the DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

It is a DOM object. To get the jQuery object you can use $(value).

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the current DOM element that your Jquery function is reffering to...
In this case your DOM element which has a class of .scrollbar is currently referred to...

As niels says, use "this" pointer to access the current DOM element.

Hope this helps :)